# Inherit from MvxAppCompatActivity

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to create my own base class that inherit from MvxAppCompatActivity.
I can use the MvxAppCompatActivity, but using passing the ViewModel gives me error.

**WORKS**

```
public class MyBaseActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
public class MyBaseActivity<T> : MvxAppCompatActivity<T>  where T : class, IMvxViewModel
```

I keep receiving the error: An unhandled exception occured.

Do I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works without any issues on my side.
Anyway, if you don´t need to re-implement MvxViewModel stuff, just do this:

```
public class BaseActivity<T> : MvxAppCompatActivity<T> where T: MvxViewModel
```